# Does the conservation of 3 and 4-momentum implies the conservation of relativistic energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics, momentum, energy-conservation

In special relativity, we require 3-momentum, 4-momentum and energy to be conserved. This gives three equations. However, after solving some exercises on relativistic dynamics, I find that I usually only use two of those equations. **So, does the conservation of two of them imply the conservation of the third?**

Comment: The temporal component of the 4-momentum *is* the energy, up to irrelevant factors of $c$, and the spatial component *is* the 3-momentum.

Answer (score 3):

The conservation of the four-momentum by itself implies the conservation of energy, the conservation of 3 momentum, and the conservation of invariant mass.